# Profiling performance of functions that call other functions

Tags: performance, r, profiling

I'm writing a relatively complex function to do a start-to-finish data analysis. This function calls lots of sub-functions I have written (which themselves call sub-sub-functions, etc.). I'm looking for a tool to tell me how much time my function is spending on each sub-function & sub-sub-function, in order to see where I should look for performance improvements. Something analagous to MATLAB's [profiler](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/profiling-for-improving-performance.html) would be nice.

For instance, a hypothetical function `audit`:

```
#fun1 is called by fun2
fun1 <- function() {
  rnorm(100000)
}

fun2 <- function(x) {
  y <- x+1
  z <- y*fun1()
}

mainFun <- function() {
  z+3
}

audit(mainFun())
> mainFun = 1 s; of which 95% is in fun1 and 98% is fun2
```

Obviously I can use `microbenchmark()` or `system.time()` for each individual function - but using this effectively becomes tricky as the `mainFun` becomes more complex. Are there ready-made tools for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Googling for `R profiler` will lead you to the `Rprof` function, which is what you are looking for. In essence, you call `Rprof()` and run your script as normal. The `summaryRprof` function is a convinient way of summarizing the result of the profiler. For more details take a look at `?Rprof` and the chapter on [Tidying and profiling R code](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Tidying-and-profiling-R-code) in [Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html), or [this link](http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=tips:misc:profiling), [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075327/getting-more-info-from-rprof), or even [this set of SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r+profiling).

Comment: Some good discussion of R profiling here, too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650862/how-to-efficiently-use-rprof-in-r

Comment: + I've used `rprof`, and I was pleased (which is going some). I don't care for the summary tool. I just grab the result file with the stack traces in it and examine those.