# Searching for a fast way to compare two matrices in R

Tags: performance, matrix, match, intersection, set-union

Given two [n,2] matrices I would like to compare them, like in the following example:

```
library('fastmatch')
    Matrix2Curt=cbind(c(1,2,3,4),c(5,6,7,8))
    Matrix2compare=cbind(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,3,9),c(5,1,2,3,3,9,3,7,6))

a=lapply(split(Matrix2compare,row(Matrix2compare)),as.numeric)
b=lapply(split(Matrix2Curt,row(Matrix2Curt)),as.numeric)

RmRowIndex=fmatch(a,b)
IndexInMatrix2comp<-which(!is.na(RmRowIndex))
RmRowIndex=na.omit(RmRowIndex)

OpenPositions=Matrix2Curt[-RmRowIndex,]
FoundPositions=Matrix2compare[IndexInMatrix2comp,]
```

I need a lot of this kind of computations in a bigger Algorithm and 90% of running time is put in the above lines.
Does someone know a faster way to calculate this?

Thank you for your help

Remarks on comments:
Yes, I put the Code in a function called setdiffMatrix() and called this function a few times:

```
$by.self


self.time self.pct total.time total.pct

".Call"             1.76    84.62       1.76     84.62

"lapply"            0.14     6.73       0.32     15.38

"as.character"      0.10     4.81       0.10      4.81

"as.factor"         0.02     0.96       0.16      7.69

"eval"              0.02     0.96       0.02      0.96

"FUN"               0.02     0.96       0.02      0.96

"match"             0.02     0.96       0.02      0.96

$by.total
total.time total.pct self.time self.pct

"setdiffMatrix"       2.08    100.00      0.00     0.00

".Call"               1.76     84.62      1.76    84.62

"fmatch"              1.76     84.62      0.00     0.00

"lapply"              0.32     15.38      0.14     6.73

"as.factor"           0.16      7.69      0.02     0.96

"split"               0.16      7.69      0.00     0.00

"split.default"       0.16      7.69      0.00     0.00

"as.character"        0.10      4.81      0.10     4.81

"eval"                0.02      0.96      0.02     0.96

"FUN"                 0.02      0.96      0.02     0.96

"match"               0.02      0.96      0.02     0.96

"match.arg"           0.02      0.96      0.00     0.00

"sort"                0.02      0.96      0.00     0.00

"sort.default"        0.02      0.96      0.00     0.00

"sort.int"            0.02      0.96      0.00     0.00

$sample.interval
[1] 0.02

$sampling.time
[1] 2.08
```

Comment: Have you tried profiling to code to see where the bottlenecks are? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13403990/profiling-performance-of-functions-that-call-other-functions